# REST Service works sometimes but not others c#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest

I have a webservice that returns customers back in json.

When I run it against the the webservice and with the following:

```
https://mywebservice/customers?Cols=first_name -- brings back all customers

try
    {
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://mywebservice/rest/customers?Cols=first_name") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Timeout = 500000;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000000;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    Log.log(response.StatusCode.ToString());
    var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
    jsonCustomers = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception i)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    }
```

It times out with a 500 error message response.

When I run it with the following:

```
https://mywebservice/customers?Cols=first_name&filter=first_name,LK,yoyo /* brings back only customers with first name like yoyo */
```

This works just fine, its almost like it is timing out but I have stated a fairly large time out period.

I have about 20K records with first_name like 'yoyo'

I have a total of over 100K records.

Thanks,

Comment: The 500 error message is an error in the webservice.  It may be you are running out of allowed memory, or taking to long to process that the webservice closes the connection with the 500 error.  You have to debug in the webservice itself to know why its erroring out.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the number of records, I know the 500 error means something is wrong on the server end but I figured since 20K records came back just fine something else was up...but okay so you don't think it is timing out due to the number of records it is returning?

Comment: Use paging and get them in smaller chunks.

Comment: Could you give an example of what that would look like please.